# MVC 5 c# - Create a website with multiple login for each user account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm looking for a tutorial how to create a website where people can register on the site. But when that user is registered he can assign another login for the same login.

I already know how to make a website with simple registration and role based.

But i'm looking for how to do what i mentioned above.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look into http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/. It is a ASP.NET Web Application Framework.

It comes pre-built with what you're looking for.